# Concatenating func_get_args into a multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I ran into this question on a different site, after attempting to work on it for an hour (could be my Sunday brains) I gave up. The question is: If there is a function `foo`:

```
function foo(){}
```

The function can be called as (arguments can be `>= 2`, where the last is always the value and the previous are part of the array).

So calling the function as:

```
foo('arg1', 'value');
```

Should result in:

```
$array['arg1'] = 'value';
```

The same if it has more than 1 argument:

```
foo('arg1', 'argx', 'argz', 'value');
```

Should produce:

```
$array['arg1']['argx']['argz'] = 'value';
```

This was my [sad attempt](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/878a568713658711ed47ace18c1657ac7aa64bd8):

```
function foo()
{
    $items = func_get_args();
    $value = array_pop($items);
    $array = array_shift($items);

    // Construct first element
    $array = array($array => array());

    foreach ($items as $el) {
       insert_last($array, $value);
    }

    return $array;
}

function insert_last(&$array, $value)
{
    $copy = $array;
    while (true) {
        $keys = array_keys($copy);
        $last = $copy[$keys[count($copy)-1]];
        var_dump($last);
        if (empty($last)) {
            $last = $value;
            break;
        }
        $copy = $last;
    }
    var_dump($array, $copy);
}
```

Pretty sure there is probably an easier solution that I just can't think of at the moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function foo()
{
    $items = func_get_args();
    $value = array_pop($items);
    $array = [];
    $arrayPtr = &$array;

    foreach ($items as $element) {
        $arrayPtr[$element] = null;
        $arrayPtr = &$arrayPtr[$element];
    }
    $arrayPtr[$element] = $value;

    return $array;
}

var_dump(foo('arg1', 'argx', 'argz', 'value'));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/onCo4)

Comment: Great thinking! I only had to update the pointer to only add the value at the end: `$arrayPtr[$element] = $value;` -> `$arrayPtr  = $value;` to avoid duplicate last entry.

Answer (score 2):

Via recursion using [call_user_func_array()](http://docs.php.net/call_user_func_array)

```
<?php
function foo() {
    $items = func_get_args();
    if ( 1==count($items) ) {
        return array_shift($items);
    }
    else {
        $key = array_shift($items);
        return array( $key=>call_user_func_array('foo', $items) );
    }
}

var_dump(foo('arg1', 'argx', 'argz', 'value'));
```

edit: same thing without func_get_args() but using a [variadic function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)

```
<?php
function foo(...$items) {
    if ( 1==count($items) ) {
        return array_shift($items);
    }
    else {
        $key = array_shift($items);
        return array( $key=>call_user_func_array('foo', $items) );
    }
}

var_dump(foo('arg1', 'argx', 'argz', 'value'));
```

Comment: Nice, I always like recursion solutions for small tasks which makes things cleaner!

Comment: Since Mark beat me to it I had to come up wth another solution ;-) But last time I checked `call_user_func_array` was a relatively costly operation. And since this is a small function and the reference's scope therefore limited I'd go with the reference instead of recursion here.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like

```
function foo()
{
    $args = func_get_args();

    $items = array_pop($args);
    foreach (array_reverse($args) as $item) {
        $items = array($item => $items);
    }

    return $items;
}

var_dump(foo('arg1', 'argx', 'argz', 'value'));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ss6Dg)